# pass custom event properties with fireEvent (testing-library and jest)

Tags: javascript, events, jestjs, react-testing-library, jsdom

#### What I would like to do

I would like to pass some custom properties to an event during some tests (using `react-testing-library` and `jest`). I am using the `fireEvent` function. I understand from the [docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-events) that the properties in the second argument are added to the event. This is what I can't do at the moment.

#### Minimal reproducible example

```
import React from 'react'
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react'
test('check event', () => {
  const DOM = render(
    <div
      onClick={event => {
        console.log(event.foo)
      }}
    >
      Click Me
    </div>
  )
  
  // here I am expecting foo to be a property on the event passed
  // to the event handler. But that doesn't happen.
  fireEvent.click(DOM.getByText('Click Me'), { foo: 'bar' })
})
```

The result is that `undefined` is logged.

#### Approaches I've tried / thoughts

I have tried various variations of this using different event types, using `createEvent`, using custom events, manually adding an event listener etc. and I can't seem to access any of the event properties I pass in with any of these variations.

I've looked under the cover a bit at what's going on in `fireEvent` [here](https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/blob/master/src/events.js). It certainly looks like those additional properties should be added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fireEvent` function allows initializing intrinsic properties of `Event` objects, but it doesn't add arbitrary properties. For example, calling

```js
fireEvent.click(DOM.getByText('Click Me'), { button: 2 })
```

dispatches a [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) with its `button` property set to 2.

Note that you may want to revisit how you're testing your component—passing custom properties to an event in a test runs counter to the guiding principle of the DOM Testing Library:

> The more your tests resemble the way your software is used, the more confidence they can give you.

However, your workflow is technically possible by passing custom properties to the `detail` property of a [CustomEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent). This approach could be feasible depending on your goals, and perhaps in conjunction with an onClick handler. For example, this logs `bar`:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import { fireEvent, render } from '@testing-library/react'

test('custom event', () => {
  const MyComponent = ({ customEventHandler, children }) => {
    const ref = useRef(null)

    useEffect(() => {
      ref.current.addEventListener('my-event', customEventHandler)

      return () => {
        ref.current.removeEventListener('my-event', customEventHandler)
      }
    }, [customEventHandler])

    return <div ref={ref}>{children}</div>
  }

  const customEventHandler = (event) => {
    console.log(event.detail.foo)
  }

  const { getByText } = render(
    <MyComponent customEventHandler={customEventHandler}>
      Click Me
    </MyComponent>
  )

  const elem = getByText('Click Me')
  const event = createEvent(
    'my-event',
    elem,
    {
      detail: {
        foo: 'bar',
      },
    },
    { EventType: 'CustomEvent' }
  )

  fireEvent(elem, event)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the very comprehensive answer :)